# Properties Of Type Class Will Reset On Build In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I've created a class that has some properties. I wanted some of those properties to be expandable in the `Property Table` so I used classes for those properties. Everything works like a charm, but when I build the project, those properties that was an instance of a class, will reset to their initial state.

This Is The Code For The Main Class:

```
Public Class MainClass
    Private m_Item As Item = New Item()

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), _
    Browsable(True)> Public Property Item() As Item
        Get
            Return m_Tab
        End Get
        Set(value As Tab)
            If Not value Is Nothing Then
                m_Tab = value
                TabChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

This Is The Class Of The Item:

```
<ToolboxItem(False), Serializable> Public Class Item
    Inherits Component
    Private m_Coords As Coord = New Coord

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), _
    Browsable(True)> Public Property Coords As Coord
        Get
            Return m_Coords
        End Get
        Set(value As Coord)
            m_Coords = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<ToolboxItem(False), Serializable, TypeConverter(GetType(CoordsTypeconverter))> _
Public Class Coord
    Private m_a As Point = New Point(0, 0)
    Private m_b As Point = New Point(0, 0)
    Private m_c As Point = New Point(0, 0)
    Private m_d As Point = New Point(0, 0)

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), _
    NotifyParentProperty(True)> Public Property A As Point
        Get
            Return m_a
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            m_a = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), _
    NotifyParentProperty(True)> Public Property B As Point
        Get
            Return m_b
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            m_b = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), _
    NotifyParentProperty(True)> Public Property C As Point
        Get
            Return m_c
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            m_c = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), _
    NotifyParentProperty(True)> Public Property D As Point
        Get
            Return m_d
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            m_d = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And This Is The Type Converter:

```
<ToolboxItem(False)> Public Class CoordsTypeconverter
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, _
                                        culture As Globalization.CultureInfo, _
                                        value As Object, _
                                        destinationType As Type) As Object

        If destinationType Is GetType(String) Then
            Dim coords As Coord = CType(value, Coord)

            Return String.Format("{0},{1} {2},{3} {4},{5} {6},{7}", _
                                coords.A.X, coords.A.Y, _
                                coords.B.X, coords.B.Y, _
                                coords.C.X, coords.C.Y, _
                                coords.D.X, coords.D.Y)
        End If

        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
    End Function
End Class
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: DesignerSerialization is for controls and components on the form.  it is not intended to save data fr code items.  You have a mish-mash of code based and Component code there.  Your "Main" class would have to be exposed to the form in order for DesignerSerialization to work , but a) it doesnt seem to actually house a collection; b) one reason to inherit Component is to avoid writing a Typeconverter, you do both; the Typeconverter lacks a ConvertFrom which might be needed; c) main lacks SHOULDxxx and RESETxxx methods.  You are close, but more info on what these are would help.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented resetxxx for every property. That worked. But I'm not satisfied with this. I wanna know more. What should I search for. I think I should mention your name in my project. You answered lots of my questions

Comment: `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` is for a collection property.  it tells VS it needs to serialize the items *in* the collection.  I cant tell if you even have a collection class.  use `,,,Visibility.Visible` for std props.  For designer serialization you should have a) a control or component b) which has a collection class of c) items.  I can only see C  and cant tell what this is or how it is implemented

Answer (score 0):

From The First Comment I Have Figured Lots Of Things.

**First:** We Should Provide `ShouldSerializeXXXX` And `ResetXXXX` For Those Properties That Are An Instance Of A Class.

**Second:** We Should Provide The Property Attribute `DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)` For Those Properties That Are An Instance Of A Class And Have Nested Properties.

**Third:** The Nested Properties Shouldn't Have The Attribute Mentioned In The Second Tip.

Thank You [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix).